cfgutil get-icon-layout throws NSInvalidArgumentException in insertObject:atIndex: object cannot be nil
I want to retrieve the home screen layout of an iPad attached with USB-C cable to my macOS device. But the command cfgutil get-icon-layout throws an NSInvalidArgumentException in insertObject:atIndex because object cannot be nil:
% cfgutil get-icon-layout        
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019d81f2ec __exceptionPreprocess + 176
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019d306788 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019d74a934 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 1288
    3   cfgutil                             0x00000001002bc1e0 cfgutil + 49632
    4   cfgutil                             0x00000001002bc0d0 cfgutil + 49360
    5   cfgutil                             0x00000001002bc0d0 cfgutil + 49360
    6   cfgutil                             0x00000001002bc4e0 cfgutil + 50400
    7   cfgutil                             0x00000001002cc6c4 cfgutil + 116420
    8   cfgutil                             0x00000001002c7bd0 cfgutil + 97232
    9   dyld                                0x000000019d3420e0 start + 2360
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
zsh: abort      cfgutil get-icon-layout

Any ideas what causes this or how to circumvent?
I also tried with -C and -K params since it's supervised, and the different --format json/text/plist params, to no avail.
Other commands work fine, the version is cfgutil 2.17 (906)
 % cfgutil list
Type: iPad13,18 ECID: 0xMYECID12345678  UDID: 00001234-56789ABCDEFFFFFF
0010281E02A3A01E Location: 0x100000 Name: Given Sur

% cfgutil version
cfgutil 2.17 (906)


Great details about cfgutil - what’s the build version on macOS? Also, does this happen with other devices (phone or pad)?
